# TFS API DefaultValue for AllowedValues

Tags: tfs

In my WITD, I have some xml like this in my FIELD tag:

```
<ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
  <LISTITEM value="Yes" />
  <LISTITEM value="No" />
</ALLOWEDVALUES>
<DEFAULT from="value" value="No" />
```

I can get the allowed values from the API by getting an instance of class FieldDefinition and referencing the AllowedValues property.

How can I get the DEFAULT tag's value from the Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new work item with a work item type that has your field and then [check the value of the field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.field.value.aspx) on the new work item. You don't need to save the work item to check the field value. It should contain the default value you are after.

Answer (score 1):

There's no API for retrieving default values. Another approach is to parse the value from the WITD XML using [`WorkItemType.Export Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemtype.export.aspx)

```
 var xml = wit.Export(false);
```